# Mockito - RxJava 2 - verify invocation

Tags: java, android, mockito, rx-java2

Is it possible to verify invocation of observables using Mockito?

My use case class:

```
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

    public Foo(Bar bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    Completable execute() {
        return bar.method1()
                .andThen(bar.method2())
                .andThen(bar.method3());
    }
}
```

My dependent class:

```
interface Bar {
    Completable method1();
    Completable method2();
    Completable method3();
}
```

And now my Test class:

```
@Mock private Bar bar;
@InjectMocks private Foo foo;

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    when(bar.method1()).thenReturn(complete());
    when(bar.method2()).thenReturn(error(new Exception()));
    when(bar.method3()).thenReturn(complete());

    foo.execute()
            .test()
            .assertError(Exception.class);

    verify(bar, times(1)).method1();
    verify(bar, times(1)).method2();
    verify(bar, times(1)).method3(); // <-- this is important part
}
```

Unfortunately, this passes, and I know why. But I want to check if the body of the observable method is invoked. For example if implementation of `Bar` is:

```
public class BarImplementation implements Bar {

    @Override
    public Completable method1() {
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("method 1"));
    }

    @Override
    public Completable method2() {
        return Completable.error(new Exception());
    }

    @Override
    public Completable method3() {
        return Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("method 3"));
    }
}
```

The "method 3" log will not be executed in production code.

Answer (score 2):

When you do your instrumentation, you need to use the same method of deferring the returned value as your production code.

```
AtomicBoolean m3Run = new AtomicBoolean(false);
...
when(bar.method3()).thenReturn(Completable.fromAction(() -> m3Run.set(true));
```

Your test can then check to see that `m3Run` has a value of `false`, as the completable will not be run unless it is subscribed to.